# How do I delete our free Stack Overflow teams account?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

How do I delete our free Stack Overflow teams account?

I do not want to delete my Stack Overflow account, just the teams account /c/spintype where I am the only user and admin.

Comment: That is not an exact duplicate because I use the free team solution. So I can't "cancelled and the remaining billing period" because I don't have a billing period.

Comment: Now that the other question is closed as a duplicate of this one, it might be good to remove "free" from the question to make it more general.

Comment: [faq-proposed]? Seems like many people will have this problem in the future.

Comment: hey @MTilsted, what did you conclude about the "delete my Stack Overflow account". I faced this same message in my Free team.

Comment: @MTilsted I meant this one: "Additionally, your team members will no longer be able to log in to Stack Overflow."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See the official help article: [Cancel your subscription](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4538417-cancel-your-subscription) which applies to Free, Basic and Business.

Goto `https://stackoverflow.com/c/spintype/admin/billing/plan`.

[image: left bar: admin settings, under billing: Plan]

Scroll down to the end of the page.

Click *Cancel subscription*.

[image: Title:Cancel your Teams subscription. Body: If you cancel your Stack Overflow for Teams subscription, you will lose access to all of your Team’s content. Additionally, your team members will no longer be able to log in to Stack Overflow. Red button: Cancel Subscription]

and confirm your cancellation. Optional you can leave feedback and prevent new users from joining the team in the confirmation step.

Comment: Ok, so it is possible to cancel the free version. Now I just have to wonder why it takes over a month before the cancel takes effect.

Comment: @MTilsted - it is a usual practice when you cancel accounts that potentially hold large amounts of data / scheduled jobs to allow customers to smoothly transition to something else or correct a grave mistake (there is also a less savvy explanation: companies think that if they prolong the agony for a month, you can change your mind).

Comment: Now the cancel option doesn't work.